# Installing Spark for Python through cgwin

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When trying to run the command:

```
sbt/sbt assembly
```

I get a message as follows:

```
$ sbt/sbt assembly
-bash: sbt/sbt: No such file or directory
```

I am already in the directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/llll/Downloads/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4`when running this command through cgwin. Do I need to move to a different directory in order for this command to run? Also when I run:

```
./bin/pyspark
```

I get an error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As one of PySpark's original authors, I do not recommend using it in Cygwin. Depending on how Python and Cygwin were set up on your computer, it's likely that you'll run into problems related to Windows vs Cygwin path-handling. In a nutshell, you'll have problems when the different processes (`spark-submit` JVM, Spark shell/executor JVMs, Python driver, and Python workers) disagree about how to handle paths. For more background on my original investigation into this issue, see https://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201402.mbox/%3CCAOEPXP5VhVfBC3xVrLDzX0PJuWSnN7sMtjBdg2qG88znw=oF+A@mail.gmail.com%3E

That said, (to my knowledge) PySpark should work in non-Cygwin Windows environments.

For the `sbt/sbt` issue, judging from your file path it looks like you downloaded the Spark 1.5.2 binary distribution for Hadoop 2.4, which should already be pre-built; the `sbt/sbt assembly` is unnecessary in this case and did not work because the source files and build scripts were not included in the binary distribution. If you'd like to build from source, you'll need to obtain a source checkout via Git or download a source archive from the Spark website.

Comment: Hi Josh. Thanks for the reply. The only reason why I want to use cgwin is because I have access to the UNIX commands. If I use the standard command prompt for Windows, I cannot use basic UNIX commands. I guess I will have to use the standard command prompt and forgo the convenience of the UNIX commands.

Comment: Also does ./bin/pyspark even work using cmd.exe? I get a message saying: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: If you're really keen on sticking to the UNIX stuff then you could just setup a Linux virtual machine (using VirtualBox or VMware Player) on your desktop . Because thats a lot less trouble than Cygwin in the long run :)